# powershell convertfrom-json select-object differences

Tags: powershell, azure-cli

Considering the below json payload (just an example snippet from "az group list"):

```
[

    {
        "id": "/subscriptions/1f512sf9-112c-4a7a-a580-665afe4761f4/resourceGroups/dev-rg",
        "location": "northeurope",
        "managedBy": null,
        "name": "dev-rg",
        "properties": {
          "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
        },
        "tags": {
          "Application": "Integrations",
          "Department": "Development Team",
          "DeployedDate": "09/01/2020",
          "Environment": "DEV",
          "FundedBy": "INT",
          "InterfaceId": "IFUS_007.1",
          "Project": "INT"
        },
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups"
      }
    ]
```

Can someone explain why the below works

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> az group list | convertfrom-json | select-object @{n='RSG';e={$_.name}}

RSG
---
{dev-rg}
```

and why the below does not (returns blank)

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> az group list | convertfrom-json | select-object name

name
----
```

Comment: Please provide valid json.

Comment: apologies - valid json supplied

Comment: the reason is that the `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet has not had access to the whole object. wrap the 1st two stages in `()` & you will get what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a Windows PowerShell bug about ConvertFrom-Json and a pipeline.

Group commands `()` so that they are evaluated properly.

```bsh
(az group list | ConvertFrom-Json) | Select-Object name
```

It's fixed in PowerShell Core.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [@7cc's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61477911/powershell-convertfrom-json-select-object-differences/61479214#61479214) answer, you could also use [`Get-AzResourceGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresourcegroup?view=azps-3.8.0) Cmdlet from Azure PowerShell, which will give you a PowerShell object to work with immediately. This is easier than converting the JSON output from Azure CLI using `az group list` to a [`System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscustomobject?view=pscore-6.2.0) with [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7).

To get all your resource groups in a column `Name`:

```
Get-AzResourceGroup | Select-Object -Property @{Name = "Name"; Expression = { $_.ResourceGroupName } }
```

Or just keep the default `ResourceGroupName` column:

```
Get-AzResourceGroup | Select-Object -Property ResourceGroupName
```